# postgresql, duplicate database which is a replication of another

Tags: postgresql

I have original `DB-original`
and have a streaming-replication `DB-replica`

I want a writable copy of `DB-replica` and did

`createdb -T DB-replica DB-copy-of-replica`

> createdb: database creation failed: ERROR:  cannot execute CREATE
>   DATABASE in a read-only transaction

How do I copy the DB?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a physical standby/replica. In physical standby, you cannot have a writeable copy of any database. If you want a writable copy of the database, you can follow either of the following:

1. Create a new cluster postgreSQL and export the database from a READ replica (physical standby) using pg_dump and pg_restore. (Refer the pg_dump/pg_restore command from PostgreSQL document)
2. You can use logical replication from the master
   https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/logical-replication-postgresql-explained

Comment: A 3rd option is to create yet another streaming replica, and then promote it so that it becomes writable.

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to change the master to the `copy` I want `DB-original` to be the master (unless it faults)